# How to redirect from a ManagedBean for when the request sent is an Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, navigation, primefaces, managed-bean

I am using PrimeFaces with JSF2. I am trying to authenticate user by sending login and password as an Ajax request. And in the action method of the backing bean, I am trying to validate user and redirect to a new view if the validation succeeds.

Is this possible while using primefaces?

Because I think with primefaces' `p:commandButton`, I can only either have ajax behavior or the navigation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, just send a redirect instead of a (default) forward as outcome. The `<navigation-case>`-less JSF 2.0 way would be appending `?faces-redirect=true` to the outcome string in the action method.

E.g.

```
public String login() {
    // ...
    return "home?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Comment: Hey! I tried it and it works perfectly and it solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Here is another technique you might find useful.  This is when you invoke method via AJAX from a Primefaces attribute that does not implement navigation.  For example, I have a p:tree object with a method selected by the nodeSelectionListener.

In that method, you can invoke redirection like this:

```
String url = (something)
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
try {
        ec.redirect(url);
} catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Navigation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: This does effectively the same, but on an old fashioned JSF 1.x way.

Comment: Works fine with JSF2.0 primeFace autoComplite. Thanks!

Comment: Very useful code, I used it for redirection after successful login in Spring Security (form-login)