# Calling Managed Bean Method From JavaScript

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have an application with a client-side image map with multiple  sections defined. I need to call a method in the Managed Bean from the `<area>` onclick attribute.

This doesn't work:

```
<area id="ReviewPerson" shape="rect" coords="3, 21, 164, 37" href="#" 
    onclick="#{personBean.method}" alt="Review Person" id="reviewPersonArea"
    title="Review Person" />
```

Since my hands are tied on the image map (unfortunately), how can I call a managed bean method from within the `<area>` tag?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have a few options.  If you are using JSF 2.0 you can build a composite component around these area tags.

The easiest way however would be to invoke a hidden JSF input button.

```
<h:commandButton id="hdnBtn" actionListener="#{personBean.method}" style="display: none;" />
```

This will render as an `input` HTML element on the page that you can access from Javascript and invoke its `click` event.

```
onclick="jQuery('#form:hdnBtn').click();"
```

Comment: Instead of **actionListener**, if we use **action** attribute then it will be easy to redirect in managed beans. [Redirect methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6026401/4067157) is not working with actionListener

Comment: What if me "personBean.method" in the backing bean has parameters (f.e a list) and I would like to pass to it? "#{personBean.method(a_list)"? Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 28):

If you use primefaces, you don't need jquery. You use remoteCommand with a name attribute, and call that name from javascript, so:

```
<area... onclick="somejavascript();"... />

<p:remoteCommand name="myCommand" actionListener="#{personBean.method}" style="display: none;" />
```

Javascript:

```
function somejavascript(){
   myCommand();
}
```

Comment: Why do I need the additional somejavascript() method? Can we not write `onclick="myCommand();"` ?

Comment: @Falco onclick="myCommand()" will merely cause personBean.method to execute.  remoteCommand is for when we need to execute something in javascript first, and only then call the bean method.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Seam, Remoting can do this for you: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/remoting.html

Another approach would be do expose the methods as REST services, and call them from your JavaScript using something like jQuery. Here's a good article on this approach: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-and-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/

Comment: Not quite what I needed since the application is designed without either approach, but upvoted since they are decent ideas and I wish we could do this as a REST service.

Answer (score 4):

If you want complete ADF Faces solution you can try this:

```
function doClick(){
   var button = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId("aButton");
   ActionEvent.queue(button,true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the most up to date answer, for **Java EE 8 (JSF 2.3)**
use `<h:commandScript>` this will create a javascript function which will under the hood invoke the jsf backing bean method, and because it's a javascript you can invoke it from your js code

**example** 
jsf

```
<h:form>
<h:commandScript id="submit" 
                 name="jsFunction"
                 action="#{bean.method}"/>
</h:form>
```

and the js code

```
</script>
        function invoke()
           {
                jsFunction();
           }
    </script>
```

for more visit [Ajax method invocation](https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html#613)

Comment: for me the jsFuntion() does return a value, I am planning to store  the  returned  value  in a  local  JS variable  but  the  invocation does  not work, any  ideas

Answer (score 0):

If you use primefaces, you can use a hidden input field linked to a managed bean, and you can initialize its value using javascript, for PrimeFaces, the PF function can be used to access a widget variable linked to the hidden input, in this way:

```
<script>
function codeLoginAddress() {
    PF('wvLoginLat').jq.val( lat1 ); // set in getLocation
    PF('wvLoginLng').jq.val( lng1 )
}
<script>

<p:inputText type="hidden" widgetVar="wvLoginLat" value="#{userSession.lat}" />
<p:inputText type="hidden" widgetVar="wvLoginLng" value="#{userSession.lng}" />

<script>
// at end of page, initialization code
getLocation(); // sets lat1 and lng1
codeLoginAddress(); // sets the value of the widget variables
</script>
```