# How do I call a javascript function from a backing bean and have the called function return a response?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have some validation going on in javascript using a mapping Class provided by a third party. They recommended it be implemented using js. I have set up my project to call the function using this:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("intersect()");
```

I am unable to figure out how to get this to return a value to the backing bean from the js. Does anyone know of a way to have the js function return a value to the backing bean after it has been excecuted? Is this possible?

Comment: You can't return something directly, but you can call a bean from javascript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619906/calling-managed-bean-method-from-javascript#28555672

Comment: In addition to @Kukeltje here's a link describing how to [pass data from javascript to the bean using p:remoteCommand.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510102/865107)